# YouTube Data API: Video list property "publicStatsViewable" seems to have no function?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.publicStatsViewable) mentions the `publicStatsViewable` boolean, but no actual description or listing of what those stats would be. This is the summary my investigations so far:

- It is not indicative of whether likes are shown or not, I've tested this.
- I cannot find a corresponding UI control to toggle it, so it seems to be an API setting only.
- Setting it to `false` does not seem to change the response when fetching video data publically (without an authenticate).

Can anyone shed any light on what this flag actually does?

Comment: Probably another bug with the API. Please check on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) or [post a ticket there](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803)